# Automation of Word using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and PrintOut issue

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a question and I'm not even sure where to turn here.

Let me first say this, in general this is working and printing out as expected and just fine.

On occasion, I have experienced a "hiccup" where Word is trying to do an {application}.Application.Printout with the parameters for the printout which are all set to "Missing". It's Office 2007.

```
WordApp.Application.PrintOut(ref zBackGround, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref OutFileName, ref   zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing, ref zMissing);
```

What is happening is in those "hiccup" situations nothing processes and nothing prints. I have a WINWORD.EXE in the Task Manager. Obviously, when I kill that process everything goes back to functioning processing the next item it needs. I have found a document that I can repeat that hiccup at will. So, basically replicate the situation.

But again, this is a variable situation for the most part.

The other interesting thing is I created a Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit virtual box in the Oracle Virtual Box as a VM. The exact same code works without any problem what so ever meaning what I was able to replicate in one environment is working as expected (printing) in the Window 7 environment.

So, I created a virtual box of Windows 2003 Server which is the same as the main server experiencing the issue. It's working there in that virtual box.

So, I moved to another server where this would not normally run at. I am experiencing the same problem there.

Does anybody information on what might cause this?

For this situation or another situation similar to this I'm ok with bypassing. Where everything works I end up trashing the printed out document and quitting (releasing the word com object anyway). Is there a way to just time the printout and if after so many seconds then just get out and quit the WordApp and then release the word com object?

This one has me a little stumped.

Answer (score 0):

This was a result of spam email arriving. I resolved the situation by just disallowing any emails to continue to process to word if there were no attachments.